# Godot: how to make a sprite follow a raycast

Tags: godot

I am making a weapon in my 2D game that will shoot at a player-market target. Is there any way to have my bullet sprite follow the raycast2D that the weapon casts?

Comment: If you edit your question to have the code for the bullet being fired and the code for the bullet, it will be possible to provide you a working answer. It's ok if the code doesn't work right, we can help fix it.

Comment: There is not enough information to provide you a complete answer. Code also gives us information about your scenes and what types of nodes you use.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a ray (aka vector), on every frame of your animation, you can calculate the position of your sprite like so

```
spritePosition2d = rayStartPosition2d + rayNormal2d * bulletSpeed * timeElapsedFromShooting
```

where `timeElapsedFromShoot` in seconds.

Feel free to give more details in the comments so I can update the answer to your requirements.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: What do you mean by rayNormal2d? when I put that in, it does not work. Can you give me the whole line in actual pure code?

Comment: @AbsolutePickle42 I can add a piece of code to your code. Please update your question with the code that casts ray, and I will add what I've described.